# VSTS automated Build failing for files not checked into source control (App.config)

Tags: git, build, automation, azure-devops

So we are just getting into VSTS with a bunch of repos that we moved over from Github and are attempting to automate our build processes. One issue that we have run into is that our builds are failing because they can't find config files that haven't been checked into source control. This is one particular message we are getting in the logs.

> App.config(0,0): Error MSB3249: Application Configuration file "App.config" is invalid. Could not find file 'd:\a\1\s\Project-Name\App.config'.

And then the build fails of course. The application we are trying to automate the build for is a simple script that has a console app with a config file containing necessary sensitive settings that we didn't want to push to Git.

I guess my question is, how do we automate a build process with VSTS when the App.Config isn't stored in Git, is there a way to push that up to the build or set it up to grab that file from somewhere? What is best practice in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For configuration files, you should keep a baseline version in source control and then transform it appropriately at the time of deployment. MSDeploy supports using `parameters.xml` / `SetParameters.xml` files to determine values at time of deployment. Or you could store a file with placeholders and replace the placeholders with actual values at the time of deployment.

Comment: I've been looking into this a bit, do you think something like this VSTS extension would do the trick on your second suggestion? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens